# How to remove a folder link from side bar in OS X Lion

Tags: finder

I've updated my OS to Lion today. But now, I can't remove the folder "maven-2.2.0" from Finder Sidebar. This folder was deleted from my computer, and I can't right click on it.

How to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold down <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> while dragging the item out.

I found this Lion change interesting; I don't necessarily like it, but I think it mirrors the way that you have to hold down ⌘ when rearranging toolbar items.

Comment: I have the same problem, but thank you so much Jtbandes, I can solve it now with hold down ⌘ and drag it out side to remove it from toolbar.